# Kingston USB stick failure

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I have a 32GB Kingston Data Traveler 100 G3 usb drive that stopped working after I unplugged it from my LG Smart TV. Now when I connect it to either my work laptop (running Linux Mint 16) it shows shortly on lsusb, and I can see it as /dev/sdb for a some seconds. Then it disapears. The same happens on my home laptop running Windows 8.1. On both of them I tried USB 2.0 and 3.0 ports, and always get the same problem.

Do you guys reckon this might be fixable (I am not worried about the data) or it's toasted and I can just throw it in the bin?

Comment: Sounds like the device was damaged, either that, it was formatted in a way neither ssytem understands.

Comment: Does it still work with the TV?

Comment: Nope, last time I checked it didn't. Although it was strange, because for a couple of times after it stopped working on the PC it would work on the TV. But after a while it stopped working altogether.